# How to supress/disable "paramiko.transport" publickey loging failures/logging for Fabric password logins?

Tags: fabric, paramiko

when i run a command in Fabric like so:

```
with settings(hide('everything'),
              host_string='myserver',
              shell='/bin/sh -c',
              no_keys=True,
              user='root',
              password='root'):
    ret = run(cmd)
```

i see the following:

```
2015-09-25 11:39:10 [paramiko.hostkeys] INFO: Unable to handle key of type ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2015-09-25 11:39:10 [paramiko.hostkeys] INFO: Unable to handle key of type ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2015-09-25 11:39:10 [paramiko.transport] INFO: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1_hpn13v11)
2015-09-25 11:39:10 [paramiko.transport] INFO: Authentication (publickey) failed.
2015-09-25 11:39:10 [paramiko.transport] INFO: Authentication (password) successful!
```

how can i stop Fabric from trying to log in using keys?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with the switch **-a, --no_agent**
As Fabric help says it forces not using the running SSH agent